# Generating images with description random

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var ImgSing: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var descrLblSign: UILabel!



var questionModel = QuestionModel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

//i been trying to make it show on the screen random images with description but i was not able to figure out of how to do it. Still learning programing.

```
    for _ in 1...5 {
        randomQuestion(queModel: questionModel)

    }


}


func randomQuestion(queModel queModel:QuestionModel){

    let questions = queModel.questions
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count)))

    descrLblSign.text = "\(questions[randomIndex].answers[questions[randomIndex].correctAnswerIndex])"

    ImgSing.image = questions[randomIndex].question






}
```

Comment: One problem I see is that you have one `UIImageView` and you try to change it five times before displaying it.  What symptoms are you seeing?

Comment: Is it shows the image and the description how I wanted to look on the screen but every time I press the next button it repeats the same image with its description and after a few try's it changes. Other times I only press the next button ones and it changes. I was thinking it was only because I have three elements on my array but I was trying not to make it repeat before I continue.

Comment: What code runs because of this "next" button?  I don't see anything.

Comment: this is the the full code where i wanted to implement the array generator without making repeat                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063864/quiz-app-with-array-without-repeating-questions