# Quiz App With Array without repeating questions

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

There is probably a better way to this app without repeating the code like I did

I'm trying to generate a different question with making it repeat from an array. But every time the action NextQuestion is pressing several times it gives me the same question several times then it goes to the next one, or other time it only press ones then it goes to the next. I know this is the best code but I'm still learning.

```
import UIKit

class TestQuestionsVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var SignImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var AnswerBtn_A: MaterialButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var AnswerBtn_B: MaterialButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var AnswerBtn_C: MaterialButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var AnswerBtn_D: MaterialButton!

    var questionModel = QuestionModel()

    var GuessQuestionNum = ""
    var answer: String = ""
    var btnLatter = ""
    var previousNumber: UInt32? // used in randomNumber()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


            for _ in 1...5 {
                        randomQuestion(queModel: questionModel)

            }


    }


    func randomQuestion(queModel queModel:QuestionModel){

        let questions = queModel.questions
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count)))

        answer = "\(questions[randomIndex].answers[questions[randomIndex].correctAnswerIndex])"

        SignImage.image = questions[randomIndex].question
        AnswerBtn_A.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[0])", forState: .Normal)
        AnswerBtn_B.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[1])", forState: .Normal)
        AnswerBtn_C.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[2])", forState: .Normal)
        AnswerBtn_D.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[3])", forState: .Normal)

        }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func ActBtn_A(sender: AnyObject) {

        GuessQuestionNum = (AnswerBtn_A.titleLabel?.text)!
        if GuessQuestionNum == answer {
            AnswerBtn_A.backgroundColor = GREEN_COLOR
        } else {
            AnswerBtn_A.backgroundColor = RED_COLOR

        }

            }

    @IBAction func ActBtn_B(sender: AnyObject) {
        GuessQuestionNum = (AnswerBtn_B.titleLabel?.text)!
        if GuessQuestionNum == answer {
            AnswerBtn_B.backgroundColor = GREEN_COLOR
        } else {
        AnswerBtn_B.backgroundColor = RED_COLOR
        }
    }

    @IBAction func ActBtn_C(sender: AnyObject) {
        GuessQuestionNum = (AnswerBtn_C.titleLabel?.text)!

        if GuessQuestionNum == answer {
            AnswerBtn_C.backgroundColor = GREEN_COLOR
        } else {
            AnswerBtn_C.backgroundColor = RED_COLOR
        }
    }

    @IBAction func ActBtn_D(sender: AnyObject) {
        GuessQuestionNum = (AnswerBtn_D.titleLabel?.text)!

        if GuessQuestionNum == answer {
            AnswerBtn_D.backgroundColor = GREEN_COLOR
        } else {
            AnswerBtn_D.backgroundColor = RED_COLOR
        }
    }

    @IBAction func NextQuestion(sender: AnyObject) {

        AnswerBtn_A.backgroundColor = BLUE_COLOR
        AnswerBtn_B.backgroundColor = BLUE_COLOR
        AnswerBtn_C.backgroundColor = BLUE_COLOR
        AnswerBtn_D.backgroundColor = BLUE_COLOR

        for _ in 1...5 {
            randomQuestion(queModel: questionModel)

        }
    }


    func randomQuestion( queModel:QuestionModel){

        let questions = queModel.questions

        func randomNumber() -> UInt32 {
            var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count))
            while previousNumber == randomNumber {
                randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count))
            }
            previousNumber = randomNumber
            return randomNumber
        }


        let randomIndex = Int((UInt32(randomNumber())))

        answer = "\(questions[randomIndex].answers[questions[randomIndex].correctAnswerIndex])"
        SignImage.image = questions[randomIndex].question
        AnswerBtn_A.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[0])", forState: .Normal)
        AnswerBtn_B.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[1])", forState: .Normal)
        AnswerBtn_C.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[2])", forState: .Normal)
        AnswerBtn_D.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[3])", forState: .Normal)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of ways to handle this. My suggestion would be to create an array of question indexes. Randomly remove an object from the array of indexes, and use it to fetch a question. Sample code:

```
import Foundation


let array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
var indexes = [Int]();

func randomItem() -> String
{
  if indexes.count == 0
  {
    print("Filling indexes array")
    indexes = (0...array.count-1).map{$0}
  }
  let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(indexes.count)))
  let anIndex = indexes.removeAtIndex(randomIndex)
  return array[anIndex];
}

for i in 1...20
{
  print("random word = \(randomItem())")
}
```

The randomItem() function is written to re-fill the indexes array once it's empty, so you get a new set of random questions.

Note that it's possible to get the same question twice in a row right after re-filling the array because the new array will contain all possible indexes, including the last one used. You'd need to add extra logic to prevent that case.